# Versiones posteriores de c++ en visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hola actualmente estoy usando la version mas actual de visual studio con c++, pero el problema es que necesito usar la version 11 de c++ para un proyecto y no se como usar esa version. Si alguien sabe como usar la version 11 de c++ en visual studio 2019 lo agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: Hola, a que te refieres con "degradar", recuerda realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Si me confundi en la pregunta, pero ya la actualice, el problema es que quiero usar la version 11 de cpp pero no se como hacerlo con vs

Comment: Ve a las opciones del proyecto, y hay eliges el estandar que quieres utilizar

Comment: no me aparece la version 11, sabes como instarla?

Comment: Es que microsoft y Visual Studio no respetan las versiones de c++ y las van incorporando según les parecen en cada diferente versión de Visual Studio. A partir de la versión 2015 me parece, se podía seleccionar el Platform Toolset, y usar el Visual Studio solo como editor, usando el compilador y las librerías de otra versión de Visual Studio que también tenías que tener instalada. En definitiva, cada versión de Visual Studio soporta ciertas cosas de cada versión de c++